# Mysql consultas joins ayuda

Tags: mysql

Me encuentro con una interrogante al momento de hacer una consulta a la base de datos mysql.

Les explico, tengo 2 tablas relacionadas (`comentarios`,`respuestas`).

La tabla `comentarios` tiene los campos `id`, `comentario`, `id_usuario` y la tabla `respuestas` tiene los campos `id`,`respuesta`,`id_comentario`,`id_usuario`.

Mi duda es que cuando me traigo los resultados no se como referenciar a los usuarios de cada respuesta. Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT comentarios.id, comentarios.comentario,comentarios.id_user, respuestas.respuesta,respuestas.id_user, usuarios,username FROM comentarios
LEFT JOIN respuestas ON respuestas.id_comentario = comentarios.id 
INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = comentarios.id_user 
WHERE comentarios.id_post=2(por ejemplo)
```

Mi cuestión es ¿como unir los usuarios de las respuestas? ¿Podría hacer un `left join`? Por favor si alguno puede ayudarme le agradecería enormemente.

Para aclarar lo que estoy intentando hacer es traerme comentarios con sus respectivas respuestas pero como ven las dos tablas tienen la referencia a la tabla usuarios. También quiero los usuarios de cada comentario y de cada respuesta.

Comment: creo que esta calro que quiero traer los comentarios y sus respuestas pero tambien indexar los usuarios de los comentarios y las respuestas el FROM vendria siendo  FROM comentarios me olvide ponerlo la query de arriba no es exatamente la query original tengo mas datos pero creo que la idea se entiende todo lo otro es redundante. Es que no tnego un buen manejo de joins estoy aprendiendo me gustaria que me ayudaran yo pensaba en un right join los usuarios de las respuesta pero no estoy muy seguro porfavor hechenme una mano

Comment: No. La verdad no es claro. Que queres decir con indexar los usuarios? que es lo que falla en ese query? que datos queres agregar a ese query? por que no mostras la salida que tenes, y la que esperas?

Comment: Ah perfecto.. ahora te entiendo.. tenes que referenciar la tabla usuarios dos veces, para traer por ejemplo el nombre del usuario. ahora si.

Comment: exacto gbianchi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin conocer exactamente como tenes las tablas, lo que tenes que hacer es consultarlas con sus usuarios ya referenciados, para evitar tener un cruce de tablas.

Vamos a hacer lo siguiente.

La Tabla A seria algo asi:

```
select (los campos que queres) 
from comentarios c inner join usuarios u on c.id_usuario = u.id_usuario
```

Esa tabla es una lista de comentarios con los usuarios, hagamos lo mismo para las respuestas

Tabla B

```
select (los campos que queres) 
from respuestas r inner join usuarios u on r.id_usuario = u.id_usuario
```

Y ahora ,lo que tenemos que hacer es unir esas dos tablas nuevas, haciendo una nueva tabla

```
select (los campos que queres)
from (
    select (los campos que queres) 
    from comentarios c inner join usuarios u on c.id_usuario = u.id_usuario) a
inner join (
    select (los campos que queres) 
    from respuestas r inner join usuarios u on r.id_usuario = u.id_usuario) b on a.id_comentario = b.id_comentario
where ...
```

Fijate que lo que hacemos aca es solamente joinear las tablas, pero no contra usuario, ya que eso ya lo joineamos previamente.

Si vas a usar un where, fijate si el mismo no se puede meter dentro de los sub selects (los selects que estan dentro del from), para evitar procesar muchos registros de mas.

Hay otra forma de hacer eso, y es la siguiente, usar un subquery en el select:

```
SELECT comentarios.id, comentarios.comentario,comentarios.id_user, respuestas.respuesta,respuestas.id_user, usuarios,username, 
       (select nombre_usuario from usuario where usuario_id = comentarios.usuario_id) usuario_comentario, 
       (select nombre_usuario from usuario where usuario_id = respuestas.usuario_id)  usuario_respuesta 
FROM comentarios
LEFT JOIN respuestas ON respuestas.id_comentario = comentarios.id  
WHERE comentarios.id_post=2(por ejemplo)
```

Comment: Exelente amigo gracias por tomarte las molestias en ayudarme, voy a probar con la subquerys en el select haber que tal va, gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: @user114682 si te dije que no te entendia, era porque realmente no te entendia ;) porfa, ya que estas, mira el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Para consulta obtener las respuestas que tiene un comentario es:

```
SELECT c.id, c.comentario, c.id_usuario, r.respuesta FROM comentarios AS c INNER JOIN respuestas AS r ON c.id = r.id_comentario WHERE c.id=2;
```

Ahora, para obtener la información del usuario hay dos casos que se presentan aquí, el primero es para obtener el usuario que hizo el comentario y el otro caso es obtener todos los usuarios que emitieron una respuesta a ese comentario.

Si deseas obtener un comentario en especifico junto con las respuestas y usuarios que las emitieron, se realiza la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT c.id, c.comentario, u.id_usuario, u.nombre, u.apellido1, r.respuesta FROM comentarios AS c INNER JOIN respuestas AS r ON c.id = r.id_comentario INNER JOIN usuario AS u ON r._usuario = s.id WHERE c.id=2;
```

Este consulta te devolverá registros solo si el comentario a buscar tiene respuestas registradas por un usuario pues con el INNER JOIN se indica que solo se devuelvan registros que tienen valores coincidentes en ambas tablas (comentarios y respuestas).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El la consulta que tu tienes usaste un LEFT JOIN, esto indica que se van a mostrar los datos de la tabla de la izquierda (comentarios) aunque estos no tengan coincidencias con la tabla de la derecha (respuestas).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto, al usar LEFT JOIN se indica que en caso de no existir respuestas registradas a ese comentario, se mostrara la información de los campos de la tabla comentarios y en la información de respuestas y usuarios se muestra un valor NULL. Lo anterior quedaría así:

```
SELECT c.id, c.comentario, u.id_usuario, u.nombre, u.apellido1, r.respuesta FROM comentarios AS c LEFT JOIN respuestas AS r ON c.id = r.id_comentario INNER JOIN usuario AS u ON r._usuario = s.id WHERE c.id=2;
```

Comment: Ok, gracias por contestar amigo si tienes razon me esta devolviendo null ne dicho caso de que un comentario no tenga respuesta pero es redundante porque se arregla con el lenguaje del lado del servidor, pero en tu ejemplo no me puedo traer ambos usuarios los de los comentarios y los de las respuestas a la vez. Sin embargo la respuesta de gbianchi dio en el calvo soluciono mi problema, la cuestion era traer ambos usuarios todo lo otro era relevante. No se si sera la consulta mas eficiente pero si es eficaz.

Comment: @user114682 si la respuesta de gbianchi te ayudó, considera marcarla como correcta e incluso votarla positivamente. Es la forma de agradecer la ayuda recibida en el sitio, e informa a otros usuarios que puedan tener el mismo problema que es una solución correcta. Un saludo.

Comment: gracias amigo soy nuevo por aqui lo hare, me tomare el timepo para leer las reglas.